# Google Drive - Uploads file sucessfully on 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: google-drive-api

As per Google best practices, Google advises to retry on suggested Google error - 500: Internal Server Error.

Please see the below server log extract - I have attempted to upload to Google which has failed (with 500: Internal Server Error) however, on querying the Google Drive box for the same file that earlier failed to upload, Google returns the meta-data for the file hence confirming that the file was indeed uploaded successfully.

This appears to be contradictory to Google's Best Practices which recommends to retry in such failure situation - on the other hand, retry would result in multiple duplicate documents in Google Drive.

```
**2013-03-11 14:36:08,477 INFO**  [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] Thread name (Begin Google Upload Process):flow.inbound-main-flow.19 - , Service Number:0736074138, Original Filename=0736074138-1362976512-01.pdf, Converted File Name=2013031114351201.pdf

**2013-03-11 14:37:32,333 ERROR** [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] Failed to upload to backup drive:Mime Type=application/pdf,serviceNumber=0736074138,localFullPath=/var/spool/0736074138-1362976512-01.pdf,FileName=-2013031114351201.pdf,FileDesc= from mate
To:0736074138
From:unknown
When:2013-03-11 14:35:12.0
Total Time:25 secs
Image Size: 1728x2167
Resolution: 204, 196 pixels/inch
Compression Scheme: CCITT Group 3
,baseFolderName=Mate, error message:500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}

**2013-03-11 14:37:42,336 ERROR** [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] Thread name (Failed Google Upload Process):flow.inbound--main-flow.19 -, Service Number:0736074138, Original  Filename=0736074138-1362976512-01.pdf, Converted  File Name=-2013031114351201.pdf

**2013-03-11 14:37:42,336 ERROR** [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] Searching customers Google Drive box for Filename:-2013031114351201.pdf

**2013-03-11 14:37:42,757 ERROR** [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] Google file to search={"etag":"\"8M2pZwE_fwroB5BIq5aUjc3uhqg/Vb9KGgCZr7aIdUrygm0HqfELaoI\"","items":[{"alternateLink":"docs.google.com/a/abc.com.au/file/d/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/edit","createdDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.383Z","downloadUrl":"doc-10-as-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/7aplsi64vdu35mnaph1ickkkr74926fi/mjsv3r4ekf50j7kgvvtdc09ah6ikvf3h/1362974400000/06957550221568715648/06957550221568715648/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M?h=09525600671296713863&e=download&gd=true","editable":true,"etag":"\"8M2pZwE_fwroB5BIq5aUjc3uhqg/MTM2Mjk3NjU3MzI1Nw\"","fileExtension":"pdf","fileSize":"7811","id":"0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M","kind":"drive#file","labels":{"hidden":false,"restricted":false,"starred":false,"trashed":false,"viewed":true},"lastModifyingUserName":"Savio Mascarenhas","lastViewedByMeDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","md5Checksum":"a77e0a2a90adcbf56a7f2cc7729a9023","mimeType":"application/pdf","modifiedByMeDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","modifiedDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","originalFilename":"-2013031114351201.pdf","ownerNames":["Savio Mascarenhas"],"parents":[{"id":"0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs","isRoot":false,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs","selfLink":".googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/parents/0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs"}],"quotaBytesUsed":"7811","selfLink":".googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M","thumbnailLink":"lh5.googleusercontent.com/7NWWsM3Kqu6rLRj1HBuDKwvL0eDnUUgbWF7Z3wy7nw7VozRD0X7SzJVX24vnZ6lWwQ=s220","title":"-2013031114351201.pdf","userPermission":{"etag":"\"8M2pZwE_fwroB5BIq5aUjc3uhqg/yT7yp2-ykNjlAtGeVoBbALyAX0U\"","id":"me","kind":"drive#permission","role":"owner","selfLink":".googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/permissions/me","type":"user"},"webContentLink":"docs.google.com/a/abc.com.au/uc?id=0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M&export=download","writersCanShare":true,"iconLink":"ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_pdf_list.png","owners":[{"kind":"drive#user","displayName":"Savio Mascarenhas","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"permissionId":"06957550221568715648"}],"lastModifyingUser":{"kind":"drive#user","displayName":"Savio Mascarenhas","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"permissionId":"06957550221568715648"},"shared":false}],"kind":"drive#fileList","selfLink":".googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+%3D+'-2013031114351201.pdf'+and+mimeType+%3D+'application/pdf'+and+trashed+%3D+false"}, Google file to search(items)=[{"alternateLink":"docs.google.com/a/abc.com.au/file/d/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/edit","createdDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.383Z","downloadUrl":"://doc-10-as-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/7aplsi64vdu35mnaph1ickkkr74926fi/mjsv3r4ekf50j7kgvvtdc09ah6ikvf3h/1362974400000/06957550221568715648/06957550221568715648/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M?h=09525600671296713863&e=download&gd=true","editable":true,"etag":"\"8M2pZwE_fwroB5BIq5aUjc3uhqg/MTM2Mjk3NjU3MzI1Nw\"","fileExtension":"pdf","fileSize":"7811","id":"0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M","kind":"drive#file","labels":{"hidden":false,"restricted":false,"starred":false,"trashed":false,"viewed":true},"lastModifyingUserName":"Savio Mascarenhas","lastViewedByMeDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","md5Checksum":"a77e0a2a90adcbf56a7f2cc7729a9023","mimeType":"application/pdf","modifiedByMeDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","modifiedDate":"2013-03-11T04:36:13.257Z","originalFilename":"-2013031114351201.pdf","ownerNames":["Savio Mascarenhas"],"parents":[{"id":"0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs","isRoot":false,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"://.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs","selfLink":"://.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/parents/0Bxjdw7torhpgMy1NMVVnamNYbGs"}],"quotaBytesUsed":"7811","selfLink":"://.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M","thumbnailLink":"://lh5.googleusercontent.com/7NWWsM3Kqu6rLRj1HBuDKwvL0eDnUUgbWF7Z3wy7nw7VozRD0X7SzJVX24vnZ6lWwQ=s220","title":"-2013031114351201.pdf","userPermission":{"etag":"\"8M2pZwE_fwroB5BIq5aUjc3uhqg/yT7yp2-ykNjlAtGeVoBbALyAX0U\"","id":"me","kind":"drive#permission","role":"owner","selfLink":"://.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M/permissions/me","type":"user"},"webContentLink":"://docs.google.com/a/abcnetworks.com.au/uc?id=0Bxjdw7torhpgQkVXaVNBb3hib3M&export=download","writersCanShare":true,"iconLink":"://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_pdf_list.png","owners":[{"kind":"drive#user","displayName":"Savio Mascarenhas","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"permissionId":"06957550221568715648"}],"lastModifyingUser":{"kind":"drive#user","displayName":"Savio Mascarenhas","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"permissionId":"06957550221568715648"},"shared":false}], Google file to search items(empty)=false 

**2013-03-11 14:37:42,758 ERROR** [GoogleDriveDispatcherImpl] File is successfully uploaded to Google: FileName = 2013031114351201.pdf
```

Comment: Please note, I had to modify the links since it was giving errors while submitting this post hence, I have deleted the "https" and "www" text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had:  I tried uploading a file, any file type, any file size, on to google drive.  But it kept giving me a `Internal Error upon Finishing`.

**My solution:**

The sharing solution that has been [posted](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/0aYK9M2F7_o%5B1-25-true%5D) did not solve the issue. I just went to my `chrome settings`, and cleared out the `Browsing Data` (Tools--> Clear Browsing Data), and checked the `Delete Cookies`, and `Empty the Cache`, from the beginning of time.  Subsequently, uploads started working for me again.